# How to efficiently print huge data inside WPF datagrid?

Tags: wpf, datagrid, printing

Datagrid contains more than 200 rows and 15 columns some cell contains graph as well.
Virtualization is enable in datagrid so datagrid doesnt have entire viusal.

Comment: Do you want to print the contents of the datagrid to a printer?  Or when you say "print" do you really mean "display on the screen"?

Answer (score 0):

The wpf datagrid is great at some things. we haven't had much luck using it with large data sets, its a bit slow and clunky. there are other products such as the xCeed grid which is good for large data sets, however it has its drawbacks as well (its harder to use). We are hoping (hope - one of the tools in this developers arsenal) that they fix this issue in the next release.